# This year's murder rate is the lowest it has been since 2000

Tags: present-perfect

I think the first sentence is correct. But is the second sentence correct? Actually I've found lots of examples like the second sentence in an English corpus.

> This year's murder rate is the lowest *it has been* since 2000.

> This year's murder rate is the lowest since 2000.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the second sentence is correct. You could consider it to be the same as the first sentence (with the italicized words simply elided), or you could consider "the lowest" (meaning "the lowest murder rate") to be a predicate nominative.